# textbox: password character (changing the letter of the word into asterisk one by one)

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a problem on my password text box in log-in form. I want it to be more precise than the others, this is what i want to know:

I will write the word "password" in the text box, if i type the first letter "p" i see that it is letter p, then if i type the second letter which is "a", the letter "p" will now become "*" while the second letter can also be seen as "a", and then it goes until the word "password" become "*******d". And then if I leave that text box the remaining letter will become "*" also.
I tried to go to the properties and look for password character, but it doesn't meet my needs.
How can i do that ?

Comment: This should be pretty simple. What have you tried?

Comment: Take a look into the events you can subscribe to. Look for something like `TextChanged`, `LostFocus`, `Leave`, etc. You didn't even tell us what type of project this is.

Comment: i tried to change the properties of the textbox "passwordchar" into "*". .
but it makes the whole word into "*"

Comment: i tell that it is a log-in form

Comment: what should i do in the events ?

Comment: We *know* what you are *trying* to do; but would like to see some effort from you. Take @GrantWinney's suggestion and look at those events.

Comment: What should you do in the events? Modify the text to match your password specifications!

Comment: yes i know it's too much, but can you give me some codes with that ?

Comment: i write something like this in the event Keypress of the textbox:
passwordTextbox.passwordChar = "*";

Comment: but i don't know what to do next ? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i create a simple example for you base on **KEY_UP** and **LEAVE** events of Textbox control.

With this code you need some additional works to take it prefect like:

Ignore Keys that are not Alphanumeric and special characters like (Back-space, Enter, Shift, Enter and...) On KEY_UP

**Test and enjoy....** ;)

```
    private void txtxPassword_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var pass = txtxPassword.Text;
        if (pass.Length < 1)
            realPass = string.Empty;
        else
            realPass += pass[pass.Length - 1];


        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
        {
            if (realPass.Length <= 1)
                realPass = "";
            else
            {
                realPass = realPass.Substring(0, realPass.Length - 2);
            }
        }
        string result = "";
        if (realPass != string.Empty)
        {

            for (var i = 0; i < realPass.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                result += "X";
            }
            result += realPass[realPass.Length - 1];
        }

            txtxPassword.Text = result;
            txtxPassword.SelectionStart = result.Length;
            lblpass.Text = realPass;
        }

    private void txtxPassword_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string result="";
        for (var i = 0; i < realPass.Length ; i++)
            {
                result += "X";
            }
        txtxPassword.Text = result;
        lblpass.Text = realPass;
    }
```

**Result:**

.............................................[image].............................................

---

**Edit**

You must keep the RealPassword in a variable. When you change the textbox.text, your RealPassword will be lost by new characters. So I declear a variable named **realPass** to keep the actual inserted password. It must be a general variabel in your class like this:

```
   private string realPass="";
```

Comment: what is realpass for?

Comment: It keep the real inserted password for you. Read the end of above answer.