# changing the textbox text to xxxx after tabbing out of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a textbox that takes social security number. I have  a requirement to change the first 5 numbers of social security number to X's  once the user tabs out of that field so if the user enters

123456789

the number should become XXXXX6789

I tried doing it using txtSSN_TextChanged event, but that causes a postback. Can I do something like this in Javascript or Jquery. Below is my C# code:

```
            string lastFourSSN = "";
            lblHidden.Text = txtssn.Text.ToString().Replace("-", "");
            lastFourSSN = Utility.Encode.GetLast(lblHidden.Text.ToString(), 4);
            txtssn.Text = "XXX-XX-" + lastFourSSN;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393608/textbox-password-character-changing-the-letter-of-the-word-into-asterisk-one-b I think this will help you out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [textbox: password character (changing the letter of the word into asterisk one by one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393608/textbox-password-character-changing-the-letter-of-the-word-into-asterisk-one-b)

Comment: this will cause the postback too. I was wondering something in jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a certainly a great idea on your part. jQuery will do the trick here.

First up, you can wire in a client side event and then turn auto-postback for that text box off (and likely you already did, since you note you never wanted a post-back for such a little task).

Ok, so your standard text box will look like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
 onchange="mychange();"  Width="280px" ClientIDMode="static" ></asp:TextBox>
```

I did add ClientIDMode static, it just makes the js more friendly to pick up the control.

And the "onchange" event is really the same as the server side post-back and change event (but of course client side).

So, our js? this works:

```
<script>
    function mychange() {
        var txt1 = $('#TextBox1');
        s = txt1.val();
        if (s.length > 5) {
            s = "XXXXX" + s.substring(s.length - 4, s.length);
            txt1.val(s);
        }
    }
</script>
```

There is no handy "right" function in js, or jQuery. But you can tweak the above a bit.

Note that substring is 0 based.

You could perhaps tweek the above. You could even remove the "if" in above, but the above quite much is a good base starting point.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't tweek the code at all. It worked right away!